# Can multiple objects be linked to one name in RMI?

Tags: java, rmi

Can multiple objects be linked *(bound)* to one name in RMI ? If that is possible whose reference will `Naming.lookup("name")` return ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's a 1:1 relationship between names and objects.  Anything else makes no sense.

You might have different implementations of the same interface, but each one has to have a unique name for looking up the proxy.

Comment: _for looking up the proxy_ means ? what do you mean proxy here ?

Comment: The proxy is the object that the client gets when it does a lookup.  It fools the client into thinking that they're dealing with a local object.

Comment: No, it isn't a 1::1 relationship. You can bind the same object to many names. You can't bind the same name to many objects though.

Comment: Good point, EJP.  I was thinking about it from the user lookup side, not the deployer's viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

> Can multiple objects be linked (bound) to one name in RMI?

No.

> If that is possible

It isn't.